# Trying to use join, count and group by, but not working as I want

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, count

I am querying my database which is a company directory. The company directory has three separate tables; Staff, Departments and Locations.

Below is an image of what my table structure looks like:
[image]

I am trying to query the database so that I can get the columns of department id, department name, location id, location name and also the number of staff members within that department. However, I also need it to list the department even if there are no staff members assigned to it just yet.

I am not sure what type of join to use, but I do know I must use a count and groupBy function.

I am still very new to SQL and am not exactly very knowledgeable just yet. I have tried one or two approaches but to no avail.

Here is my attempt, which does bring results as I wanted, but it excludes departments which have no staff members.

```
SELECT p.id, p.lastName, p.firstName, p.jobTitle, p.email, d.id, 
    d.name as department, l.name as location, COUNT(*) as totalStaff 
FROM personnel p 
LEFT JOIN department d ON (d.id = p.departmentID) 
LEFT JOIN location l ON (l.id = d.locationID) 
GROUP BY (d.id)
```

Is anyone able to assist?

Comment: Pretty sure this was asked by you a few hours ago. At least your last question contained an attempt at a query

Comment: Its always nice with an sql question to provide a schema and some test data all as copy/paste able text. Pictures are really unhelpful Or as a SQLFiddle.

Comment: I got called away when I saw the previous question, I seem to remember thinking you needed to use `FROM department LEFT JOIN the other 2 tables` then you will always get the Department data

Comment: Hi Riggs! Yes, sorry about that. I was thinking I needed to explain myself again but in a better way. I had to clarify my explanation a bit more. I have updated with my original query attempt if that helps again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from department and left joining the other 2 tables will ensure you always get all the dept info which I seem to remember was your original issue in the previous question

```
SELECT p.id, p.lastName, p.firstName, p.jobTitle, p.email, 
        d.id, d.name as department, 
        l.name as location, 
        COUNT(p.id) as totalStaff 
FROM department d
    LEFT JOIN personnel p ON (d.id = p.departmentID) 
    LEFT JOIN location l ON (l.id = d.locationID) 
GROUP BY (d.id)
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` should be `COUNT(p.id)` so you don't count the `NULL` value for departments with no personnel.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar

Comment: A massive thanks to you @RiggsFolly !! It is working exactly how I want :)